# oracle - ORA 06533 subscript beyond count

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am getting a `ORA-06533` when executing a package. There are several things involved and i'll try my best to be as detailed as possible.

First we have these type objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYP_REPORT_IC_OBJ AS OBJECT (
     INTERNAL_DCN  VARCHAR2(30)
    ,IC_ID        VARCHAR2(100)
    ,IC_NUM       NUMBER(38)
    ,IC_CODE      VARCHAR2(15)
    ,CM_CODE      VARCHAR2(7)
    ,IC_VERSION   VARCHAR2(2)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYP_REPORT_IC_TAB IS TABLE TYP_REPORT_IC_OBJ;
```

In package spec I have defined types (only showing relevant):

```
TYPE TYP_REPORT_REC IS RECORD (report_ic_tab TYP_REPORT_IC_TAB);
TYPE TYP_REPORT_TAB IS TABLE OF TYP_REPORT_REC INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

In the body I have a function which is building a dynamic query (again only showing relevant code):

```
FUNCTION open_report_cur_f 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
v_select_common   VARCHAR2 (20000) :=
               CHR (10)
            || ',CAST(MULTISET(SELECT'                                
            || CHR (10)
            || '                 c.INTERNAL_DCN'
            || CHR (10)
            || '                ,c.IC_ID'
            || CHR (10)
            || '                ,c.IC_NUM'
            || CHR (10)
            || '                ,c.IC_CODE'
            || CHR (10)
            || '                ,c.CM_CODE'
            || CHR (10)
            || '                ,DECODE(c.IC_VERSION,''10'',''0'',NVL(c.IC_VERSION,''9'')) IC_VERSION'
            || CHR (10)
            || '               FROM REPORT_IC c'
            || CHR (10)
            || '               WHERE c.internal_dcn = cr.internal_dcn'
            || CHR (10)
            || '               AND   rownum <= '
            || G_IC_LIMIT
            || ') AS TYP_REPORT_IC_TAB) AS REPORT_IC_TAB';
```

And a procedure which uses the function (again only showing relevant code) and `TYP_REPORT_TAB`. Error occurs right below comment line:

```
PROCEDURE Put_Records_p
IS
  TYPE REPORT_TABLE_TYPE IS REF CURSOR
     RETURN TYP_REPORT_REC;
   cur_claim_report          REPORT_TABLE_TYPE;
   v_t_report                TYP_REPORT_TAB;
   v_text_line_temp          VARCHAR2 (32767);

          BEGIN
             SELECT TO_DATE (variable_value, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
               INTO g_effective_date
               FROM SYSTEM_CONFIG
              WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'EFFECTIVE_DATE';
          EXCEPTION
             WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
             THEN
                g_effective_date := TO_DATE ('04/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
          END;

     cur_cl_report := open_report_cur_f;

     LOOP
        FETCH cur_cl_report
        BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_report
        LIMIT G_BULK_LIMIT;

        IF (v_t_report.COUNT = 0)
        THEN
           EXIT;
        END IF;

        FOR i IN v_t_report.FIRST .. v_t_report.LAST
        LOOP
          IF v_t_report (i).CM_DOI < g_effective_date
          THEN
             v_text_line_temp := v_text_line_temp || RPAD (' ', 1);
          ELSIF v_t_report (i).CM_DOI >= g_effective_date
          THEN
--Line number pointed to below portion. I'm not sure what needs to be added or modified to avoid having the error.
             v_text_line_temp :=
                   v_text_line_temp
                || RPAD(NVL(v_t_report (i).report_ic_tab (1).IC_VERSION, 
                            '0'),
                        1,
                        '0');
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
END;
```

It seems to be complaining when building the string `v_text_line_temp` with a `ORA-06533 Subscript beyond count`.

**UPDATE:** After Justin's comment, I tried adding IF conditional where the error occurs to process only if it is `NOT NULL`:

```
          IF v_t_report (i).report_ic_tab IS NOT NULL
          THEN
             v_text_line_temp :=
                   v_text_line_temp
                || RPAD(NVL(v_t_report (i).report_ic_tab (1).IC_VERSION,
                            '0'),
                        1,
                        '0');
          END IF;
```

But error still occurs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that you've left something important out.  Your `if v_t_report(i).cm_doi < g_effective_date` line implies that `v_t_report` has been initialized and has some data elements.  It also assumes that a variable `i` is declared.  Neither are true about the code you've posted.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for pointing that out, I have updated the missing information.

Comment: OK.  How do you know that the `report_ic_tab` collection in `v_t_report(i)` has an element at index 1?  I would guess that in at least one case that collection is NULL.

Comment: @JustinCave So the error is occurring because there may be `NULL` values? Shouldn't the `NVL` function take care of `NULL` values?

Comment: If `v_t_report(i).report_ic_tab` is NULL then referencing the element at index 1 will throw the subscript beyond count error.  That will happen before the `NVL` call.  I don't know that is the source of your error since you don't have a reproducible test case.  But it's a guess consistent with the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave, checking v_t_report (i).report_ic_tab.COUNT > 0 seemed to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Change how you are iterating through your collection...

Rather than using

```
    FOR i IN v_t_report.FIRST .. v_t_report.LAST
```

try

```
    FOR i IN 1.. v_t_report.COUNT
```

example:

```
    PROCEDURE Put_Records_p
    IS
      TYPE REPORT_TABLE_TYPE IS REF CURSOR
         RETURN TYP_REPORT_REC;
       cur_claim_report          REPORT_TABLE_TYPE;
       v_t_report                TYP_REPORT_TAB;
       v_text_line_temp          VARCHAR2 (32767);

              BEGIN
                 SELECT TO_DATE (variable_value, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                   INTO g_effective_date
                   FROM SYSTEM_CONFIG
                  WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'EFFECTIVE_DATE';
              EXCEPTION
                 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                 THEN
                    g_effective_date := TO_DATE ('04/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
              END;

         cur_claim_report := open_report_cur_f;

         LOOP
            FETCH cur_claim_report
            BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_report
            LIMIT G_BULK_LIMIT;

            FOR i IN 1..v_t_report.COUNT
            LOOP
              IF v_t_report (i).CM_DOI < g_effective_date
              THEN
                 v_text_line_temp := v_text_line_temp || RPAD (' ', 1);
              ELSIF v_t_report (i).CM_DOI >= g_effective_date
              THEN
    --Line number pointed to below portion. I'm not sure what needs to be added or modified to avoid having the error.
                 v_text_line_temp :=
                       v_text_line_temp
                    || RPAD(NVL(v_t_report (i).report_ic_tab (1).IC_VERSION, 
                                '0'),
                            1,
                            '0');
              END IF;
            END LOOP;

            EXIT WHEN cur_cl_report%NOTFOUND;
         END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Could you please explain how/why this may address the issue i'm having?